# Ajax beforeSend works only once on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have 3 files:

index.html.erb is my homepage

inside the index I render a partial, _relationship.html.erb, and there is a form with the following line:

```
<%= form_tag('/relationships/update/', :remote => true, :id => "relationships_form_#{@count}") do %>
```

i also have index.js.erb (relationship.html is in index.html.erb)

```
jQuery("#relationships_form_1").bind("ajax:success", function() {
  $("#box_relationships").hide().html("<%=escape_javascript(render('relationships/relationships'))%>").fadeIn(2000, 'swing');
  })
```

the form is sent every time, and the value is changed.

i want to show a loading gif using the beforeSend option.

I tried (on index.html.erb. if i put it in the _relationships partial, it doesn't work at all):

```
jQuery("#relationships_form_1").bing("ajax:beforeSend", function() {
$("#relationship_save").show();
});
```

But it works only once.

Then, i added the before rails option

```
:before => '$("#relationship_save").show();'
```

It works, again, only once.

I even tried the .on on jquery

```
    jQuery("#relationships_form_1").on("ajax:beforeSend", function() {
$("#relationship_save").show();
});
```

And it still works only once.

The form is sent every time, the value is stored every time, the beforesend works only once

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).on("ajax:beforeSend", "#relationships_form_1", function() {
  $("#relationship_save").show();
});
```

Because your ajax-loaded form is not the same as initial form.

Comment: Excelent... great contribution